# How to post data to the table from POSTMAN client

Tags: mysql, json, spring-data-rest, postman

I am developing a shoppingcart application in spring-data-rest. I am testing my application from POSTMAN client. In my application I have Cart table and Cart_item table.  Cart_item  table has cart_id field which will get id from Cart. I am able to PUT data to Cart and Cart_item individually. But I am not interested to PUT data individually. Hoe can i send  cart data and cart_item data in a single JSON.

I am able to insert into cart table with the following JSON:
    cart url in POSTMAN: http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/carts

```
{
  "date": "2015-10-10",
  "totalAmount": 1000,
   "createdAt": "2015-04-06T18:30:00.000+0000",
   "updatedAt": "2015-04-09T18:30:00.000+0000",
   "sport":"http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/sports/1",
   "user":"http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/users/9090909090",
   "tenant": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/tenants/2"
  }
```

For cart_item: http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/cartItems

```
  {
  "rate": 500,
  "quantity": 2,
  "amount": 1000,
  "createdAt": "2015-04-12T23:40:00.000+0000",
  "updatedAt": "2015-04-14T21:35:20.000+0000",
   "merchandise": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/merchandises/10",
  "cart":"http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/carts/901",
  "merchandiseType":"http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/merchandiseTypes/1"
  }
```

How can i PUT the data into cart and cart_item table from  a single JSON request?

I tried following  way but cart is being added but  cart_item is not created in cart_item table: URL: http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/carts

```
  {
   "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/cartItems":
      {
       "rate": 50,
       "quantity": 1,
       "amount": 50,
       "createdAt": "2015-04-12T23:40:00.000+0000",
       "updatedAt": "2015-04-14T21:35:20.000+0000",
       "merchandise": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/merchandises/10",
       "merchandiseType":"http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/merchandiseTypes/1"
        },
     "date": "2015-10-10",
     "totalAmount": 99898,
     "createdAt": "2015-04-06T18:30:00.000+0000",
     "updatedAt": "2015-04-09T18:30:00.000+0000",
     "sport":"http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/sports/1",
     "user":"http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/users/9090909090",
     "tenant": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/tenants/2"
   }
```

Can anyone please help me..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think these are 2 separate requests that will need to be created separately in postman, alternatively you could send these 2 requests automated using curl/bash instead? hope that helps

Comment: @Filype Thanks for replay. cart_item table has a field cart_id which refers the id in cart table.  can you give a example how can i send request using curl in my scenario?

Comment: @Filype How can i test it from POSTMAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman is a great tool to talk to APIs, but it won't do what you need to do. It seems that you need more than just building an HTTP request (that's what postman do).

The approach I see would be:

- send a PUT to carts API
- store card_id from the response
- send a PUT to cart_item using `card_id` (from the first request)

There are a number of ways to do this outside of postman, one option that is easy if you are in a linux/mac environment is to use curl/awk/grep

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fliype.  So, i need to do it from my coding part to get cart_id and then send PUT to cart_item.

Comment: Postman can do this too but it requires an upgrade: http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/

Comment: That's awesome @Abhinav - that's definitely what MAK is after. Excellent work on the postman